# Unable to do "npm install --save firebase"

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native

I have used firebase right up to yesterday morning, then suddenly in the afternoon "npm install --save firebase" stopped working with the error:

> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near
>   '...anary.9678bf9.tgz","f'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\manjot\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-11-04T05_47_36_550Z-debug.log

I've tried updating my node.js from 10 to 13.0.1, uninstalling and installing, clearing cache, restarting my computer, a new project, doing all of this with admin cmd, googled a bit but no luck so far. 
Why did it suddenly stop working and how to fix this issue? I can still do things like

> "npm install --save react-navigation"

or

> "npm install --save react-navigation-stack"

Comment: try once npm audit fix. It will scan your project for vulnerabilities and automatically install any compatible updates to vulnerable dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the latest released version of firebase npm module is corrupted somehow and npm is failing to parse the tgz file for the lib. If it was me I would go and look at their releases page look for a previous version you know works and install that version.

`npm install firebase@x.y.z` for example

I would also say, be sure to use a `package-lock.json` file to lock down working versions of modules.

Answer (score -1):

The same problem happened to me one day.

- Delete the `npm_modules` directory
- run `npm install` command

It worked for me!